# Persisting data received by GCM push after Activity has been killed

Tags: android, memory-management, google-cloud-messaging

Assuming that Android has killed my process to free up memory (`onSaveInstanceState` has been called in my Activity), and afterwards I receive a push message, what's the best way to store the information in the push message, so that the Activity can retrieve it later when the Activity is restarted?

I'm currently looking at `SharedPreferences`, but it only allows me to store primitives while the data structure I wish to store has structure to it.

Perhaps I could serialize to JSON and store into `SharedPreferences` as a `String`, but I'm wondering if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you send in a GCM message to your app from your server becomes key/value pairs in the extras of the intent of the BroadcastReceiver that handles that message.

A common practice of handling GCM messages is to display a notification which opens an activity of your app when clicked. You can pass all the key/value pairs of the message to the intent that starts the activity, so your activity will have all the data, regardless of whether it was previously killed or not.